# Merging two excel sheets in to One Excel work book without loading them in to memory

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Folks,

We have one requirement where we want to merge two excel sheets in to one workbook using JAVA.

We know this can be done with Apache POI.

But we donot want to do following. We just want to merge these two excel files in to single workbook.

Donot do : Load both Excel file in to memory. Their contents are huge more than 100k rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok we have to copy cell by cell or raw by row. Question here is we donot want to do it by loading entire excel file in to memory (content is huge). Is it possible to load the chunk of one sheet and write in to other sheet which is present in other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy sheet to another workbook. You need to create you a new workbook, then create a sheet and add cell by cell the content of your sheets.

I can help you with 2 methods to copy row, and copy cell and depending method:

```
/**
 * Copy row with style and merged region. This manage a shift in copy. You can copy row 1 to 10 and paste it between. this method can be use for copying in same sheet
 * 21 and 30
 * @param pSrcSheet source sheet
 * @param pDestSheet dest sheet
 * @param pSrcLine line to copy
 * @param pDestLine line to paste
 * @param pStyleMap just get a new HashMap<Integer, CellStyle> pStyleMap
 * @param pLineShift the shift set 0 if you don't need to shift your row. Example copy row 1 to 10 and paste it between 21 and 30 you
 *            need set thhe shift value 20. The value could be negative to pick up the data
 */
public static void copyRow(Sheet pSrcSheet, Sheet pDestSheet, Row pSrcLine, Row pDestLine,
    Map<Integer, CellStyle> pStyleMap, int pLineShift)
{
    ArrayList<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = getMergedRegions(pDestSheet);
    pDestLine.setHeight(pSrcLine.getHeight());
    for (int j = pSrcLine.getFirstCellNum(); j < pSrcLine.getLastCellNum(); j++)
    {
        Cell oldCell = null;
        Cell newCell = null;
        // if no cell in row skip the iteration
        if (j >= 0)
        {
            oldCell = pSrcLine.getCell(j);
            newCell = pDestLine.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        }

        if (oldCell != null)
        {
            if (newCell == null)
            {
                newCell = pDestLine.createCell(j);
            }
            copyCell(oldCell, newCell, pStyleMap);
            CellRangeAddress mergedRegion =
                getCurrentMergedRegion(pSrcSheet, pSrcLine.getRowNum(), (short) oldCell.getColumnIndex());
            if (mergedRegion != null)
            {
                CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion =
                    new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow() + pLineShift, mergedRegion.getLastRow()
                        + pLineShift, mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(), mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
                if (isNewMergedRegion(newMergedRegion, mergedRegions))
                {
                    mergedRegions.add(newMergedRegion);
                    pDestSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedRegion);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Copy cell with style from same workbook or not
 * @param pOldCell
 * @param pNewCell
 * @param pStyleMap
 */
public static void copyCell(Cell pOldCell, Cell pNewCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> pStyleMap)
{
    if (pStyleMap != null)
    {
        if (pOldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == pNewCell.getSheet().getWorkbook())
        {
            pNewCell.setCellStyle(pOldCell.getCellStyle());
        }
        else
        {
            int stHashCode = pOldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
            CellStyle newCellStyle = pStyleMap.get(stHashCode);
            if (newCellStyle == null)
            {
                newCellStyle = pNewCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(pOldCell.getCellStyle());
                pStyleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
            }
            pNewCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
        }
    }
    switch (pOldCell.getCellType())
    {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            pNewCell.setCellValue(pOldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            pNewCell.setCellValue(pOldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            pNewCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            pNewCell.setCellValue(pOldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            pNewCell.setCellErrorValue(pOldCell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            pNewCell.setCellFormula(pOldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

/**
 * return the cellRangeAdress of the merge region where the cell is. Null if the cell is not in merged region
 * @param pSheet
 * @param pRowNum
 * @param pCellNum
 * @return return the cellRangeAdress of the merge region where the cell is. Null if the cell is not in merged
 *         region
 */
public static CellRangeAddress getCurrentMergedRegion(Sheet pSheet, int pRowNum, int pCellNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
    {
        CellRangeAddress merged = pSheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (merged.isInRange(pRowNum, pCellNum))
        {
            return merged;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * return the index of the merge region where the cell is. -1 if the cell is not in merged region
 * @param pSheet
 * @param pRowNum
 * @param pCellNum
 * @return return the index of the merge region where the cell is. -1 if the cell is not in merged region
 */
public static int getCurrentMergedRegionIndex(Sheet pSheet, int pRowNum, int pCellNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
    {
        CellRangeAddress merged = pSheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (merged.isInRange(pRowNum, pCellNum))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * return the cellRangeAdress of the merge region where the cell is. Null if the cell is not in merged region
 * @param pSheet
 * @param pRowNum
 * @param pCellNum
 * @return return the cellRangeAdress of the merge region where the cell is. Null if the cell is not in merged
 *         region
 */
public static ArrayList<CellRangeAddress> getMergedRegions(Sheet pSheet)
{
    ArrayList<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
    {
        mergedRegions.add(pSheet.getMergedRegion(i));
    }
    return mergedRegions;
}

/**
 * verify all boolean are true
 * @param pValues
 * @return
 */
public static boolean areAllTrue(boolean... pValues)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pValues.length; ++i)
    {
        if (pValues[i] != true)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Compare 2 region if they are the same return true
 * @param pRegion region compare to pRegion2
 * @param pRegion2 region compare to pRegion
 * @return true if the region are the same, false if region are different
 */
public static boolean cellRangeAdressEquals(CellRangeAddress pRegion, CellRangeAddress pRegion2)
{
    boolean r1 = (pRegion.getFirstRow() == pRegion2.getFirstRow());
    boolean r2 = (pRegion.getLastRow() == pRegion2.getLastRow());
    boolean c1 = (pRegion.getFirstColumn() == pRegion2.getFirstColumn());
    boolean c2 = (pRegion.getLastColumn() == pRegion2.getLastColumn());
    return areAllTrue(r1, r2, c1, c2);
}

/**
 * Verify the it's a new region or existing
 * @param pNewMergedRegion
 * @param pMergedRegions
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress pNewMergedRegion,
    ArrayList<CellRangeAddress> pMergedRegions)
{

    boolean isNew = true;
    int i = 0;
    // we want to check if newMergedRegion is contained inside our collection
    while (pMergedRegions != null && i < pMergedRegions.size() && isNew)
    {
        if (cellRangeAdressEquals(pMergedRegions.get(i), pNewMergedRegion))
        {
            isNew = false;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return isNew;
}
```

you can find some help on this thread : http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-excel

If you have more information about your problem, I will help you as i can ;)